# github php project deployment

Tags: php, deployment, capistrano, setup-deployment

I have a project which has the codes in github (a private repo), I am looking for a good way to deployments for this.

I know capistrano, but not sure whether there are any better solutions, wanting to check other opinions :)

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you had a look at the existing topics? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+deploy

Comment: I thought of going forward with capistrano for this, 

I will post my build file here (without the server details and the project details ) 

and this link [http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/][1]


  [1]: http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/ was a help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a PHP developer you may want to look at [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/). It can do a git checkout and deploy using SSH and much more. The big advantage over Capistrano is that it is built with PHP, and may be easier for you and your team.

Answer (score 1):

I would give Dandelion a shot: https://github.com/scttnlsn/dandelion

Dandelion allows you to push any new git changes to an SFTP or FTP host.  Assuming you don't actually need to perform any "deploy" actions other than transferring the source files, it is simpler than using Capistrano.  You will need Ruby.

Comment: i need to do this via SSH, so every thing has to happen through SSH, and there is a data base update which I need to run after the codes are copies, a simple shell command in the server's root

Comment: sftp operates over ssh.  so you could use this and then manually run your command.  or use something like Capistrano, or Fabric (a similar tool in Python: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html)

Comment: thanks for the info, i didnt know about Fabric, gotta check it out

Comment: well after some research I thought of going with capistrano